# getting error while render data from API in react native

Tags: react-native

i am trying to render data from two API'S (type:GET)but when i render data from first Api it gives me what i want but when i did same thing with second Api it gives me error like this 
**( Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id,name} ...). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead)**

here is my code of state
constructor(props) {

```
      super()
       constructor(props) {
    super(props){this.state={gender:{},races:[]}
```

now here is my API's call

```
componentDidMount()
{
axios.get("http://172.104.217.178/blaze10/public/api/genders")
    .then((response) => {
       alert(JSON.stringify(response));
          this.setState({
          gender:response.data


        });
          alert(this.state.gender)

       })
           .catch(error => alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data)));


    //here i call second api races////

       axios.get("http://172.104.217.178/blaze10/public/api/races")
           .then((response) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(response));
          this.setState({
        races:response.data
    });
    //alert(this.state.gender)
     })
      .catch(error => alert(JSON.stringify(error)));
       }
```

here is my code which i writ in my render function

```
 let gender = [];
  let race = [];

  let stateGender = this.state.genderr;
 // alert(typeof stateGender);
 for(let property in stateGender){
  gender.push(<Picker.Item label={stateGender[property]} value={property} />);
 }




 let stateRace = this.state.races;
// alert(typeof stateGender);
for(let property in stateRace){
race.push(<Picker.Item label={stateRace[property]} value={property} />);
}


        and this is my picker components code where i want to show my api 
               data ..
        <Item picker >
    <Left>
   <Text style= 




         {{paddingLeft:10,fontSize:15,fontWeight:'bold'
       }}> Gender</Text>
   </Left>
   <Body>
      <Picker 
        mode="dropdown"
        iosIcon={<Icon name="ios-arrow-down-outline" />}
        style={{ width: '100%' }}

        placeholder="Select Gender"

        placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
        placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
        selectedValue={this.state.gender1}
        onValueChange={(value)=>this.onValueChange(value,'gender')}


      >
        {/* {gender} */}
      </Picker>
      </Body>
    </Item>
```

and here is my second component where i want to show my second api data

```
 <Item picker >
        <Left>
       <Text style={{paddingLeft:10,fontSize:15,fontWeight:'bold',color:this.state.backgroundColor3}}> RACE</Text>
       </Left>
       <Body style={{paddingLeft:10}}>
          <Picker 
            mode="dropdown"
            iosIcon={<Icon name="ios-arrow-down-outline" style={{paddingLeft:8}}/>}
            style={{ width: '100%' }}

            placeholder="Select Race"

            placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
            placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
            selectedValue={this.state.race}
            onValueChange={(value)=>this.onValueChange(value,'race')}
          >
            {race}
          </Picker>
          </Body>
          </Item>
          <Item picker >
          <Left>
```

**PROBLEM**

when i run my application boths api calls and give me data in responce and first api show me data in my picker component but second api give me error which i mention above .....please help

Comment: Second component looks wired. How about show full `render` area?

Comment: i just want to show my second api data into second component

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that what you're trying to render inside a component (view, picker item etc) is not an object but a string property
If your race is an object you cannot render it like this {race}. Instead you need to do it like this: {race.property},and make sure that this property is also not an object. This is what is causing your error.

Comment: yup i did with {race.property } but nothing shows up there :(

Comment: any other suggestions ?

Comment: your gender is an object, the race is an array. If you have objects in this array you need to reference the index like race[0].property. Can you please post the content of the {race} before you try to render it?

Comment: which content u r asking for ?

Comment: @bilalahmad123456 the thing you want to render but gives you error.

Comment: for(let property in stateRace){
    race.push(<Picker.Item label={stateRace[property].name} value={stateRace[property].id} />);
    }

Comment: i find the solution above coment is a solution